# ¿como hacer un selector de pais y cuidad?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, diseño

solo quiero sugerencias para hacer 2 selectores, uno de pais, y que el otro me traiga las cuidades, ya tengo el diseño de ambos, solo me hace falta alguna idea para cargar los paises y cuidades.
ya sea mediante algun bean,dao,clase e incluso base de datos, si me pudieran ayudar, seria lo mejor, como dice el dicho, hoy por mi, mañana por ti....

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="departamento"  
                                     style="width:170px" 
                                     required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="Por favor, seleccione un departamento" 
                                     filter="true"
                                     filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                     panelStyle="width:200px"> 
                        <p:ajax update="cuidad" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un departamento" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />                        
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:outputLabel for="cuidad" value="Cuidad" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="cuidad"  
                                     style="width:160px" 
                                     required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="Por favor, seleccione una Cuidad"  
                                     filter="true"  
                                     filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                     panelStyle="width:200px">                        
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione una cuidad" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />                        
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

uidades del mismo,

Answer (score 0):

Para la implementación de un selector de país y ciudad 
Te puedo recomendar lo siguiente:

1. puedes hacer que cargue el listado de países en el
   postconstructor del Bean esto con el fin de  Tenerlos visibles en el
   componente Select
2. una vez que se seleccione el país puedes agregar o implementar un
   componente de JSF    Llamado change e implementar un método en donde
   reciba el id del país seleccionado      Buscar las ciudades
   principales  y las regrese por medio de una lista y así cada vez que
   seleccionas un  País  consultas  y  traer un listado de las ciudades
   correspondientes

   ```
   --front end
   <p:outputLabel for="city" value="Editable: " />
   <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{selectOneMenuView.city}" >
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuView.cities}" />
   </p:selectOneMenu>



   // bean     
   private String city;  
   private Map<String,String> cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
   // get and set 

   public String getCity() {
       return city;
   }

   public void setCity(String city) {
       this.city = city;
   }
    public Map<String, String> getCities() {
       return cities;
   }

    @PostConstruct
   public void init() {

       //cities
       cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
       cities.put("New York", "New York");
       cities.put("London","London");
       cities.put("Paris","Paris");
       cities.put("Barcelona","Barcelona");
       cities.put("Istanbul","Istanbul");
       cities.put("Berlin","Berlin");
   }
   ```

Comment: ¿y donde agrego los paises?

Comment: En el método init() agregas los diferentes países supongo que tienes una conexión a la base de datos  y te regresa una lista entonces lo que haces es que esa lista la almacene en la variable cities para ser visualizadas